# build_person_to_matches

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

d= dictionary

want to functin to be able to return `{'John':1,'Mark':3}`

```
def build_person_to_matches(d, name): '''(dict of {str: list of str}, str) -> dict of {str: int}'''
    collect = 0
    for books in d[name]:
        for person in d.keys():
            if books in d[person]:
               collect += 1
        d[person] = collect
    return d
```

but the function does not work with the following example:

```
build_person_to_matches({'Tom': ['fiction', 'documentary', 'science'],'John': ['computer science', 'math'],'Jack': ['science', 'computer science', 'math', 'chemistry']}, 'Jack')
```

Comment: what is the expect output from the example at end? {'John':1,'Mark':3}? what?

Comment: ｛'Tom': 1, 'John':2, 'Jack' : 4}

Comment: Please don't destroy questions -- that removes whatever use the answers people spent time to craft might have.

Answer (score 1):

first, you should separate the dictionary that was passed in, and the dictionary that you are going to return.

```
def build_person_to_matches(d, name):
    ret = {}
    collect = 0
    for books in d[name]:
        for person in d.keys():
            if books in d[person]:
               collect += 1
        ret[person] = collect
    return ret

d = {
    'Tom': ['fiction', 'documentary', 'science'],
    'John': ['computer science', 'math'],
    'Jack': ['science', 'computer science', 'math', 'chemistry']
}
print build_person_to_matches(d, 'Jack')
```

Second, switch the order of the two for loops, and move the `collect = 0` line into the first loop.

```
def build_person_to_matches(d, name):
    ret = {}
    for person in d.keys():
        collect = 0
        for books in d[name]:
            if books in d[person]:
               collect += 1
        ret[person] = collect
    return ret

d = {
    'Tom': ['fiction', 'documentary', 'science'],
    'John': ['computer science', 'math'],
    'Jack': ['science', 'computer science', 'math', 'chemistry']
}
print build_person_to_matches(d, 'Jack')
```

Optionally, for the sake of readability, you may as well move the inner loop into its own function, to make it more obvious to the reader what is going on.

```
def how_many_genres_both_people_like(d, person_a, person_b):
    total = 0
    for books in d[person_a]:
        if books in d[person_b]:
           total += 1
    return total

def build_person_to_matches(d, name):
    ret = {}
    for person in d.keys():
        ret[person] = how_many_genres_both_people_like(d, name, person)
    return ret

d = {
    'Tom': ['fiction', 'documentary', 'science'],
    'John': ['computer science', 'math'],
    'Jack': ['science', 'computer science', 'math', 'chemistry']
}
print build_person_to_matches(d, 'Jack')
```

Output:

```
{'John': 2, 'Jack': 4, 'Tom': 1}
```

Comment: the instruction was to write one function

Answer (score 0):

```
for entry in d:
    print(entry + ':' + str(len(d[entry])))
```

(replace print with return if you're putting it in a function)

That runs through each entry in dictionary 'd' and then finds the length of the corresponding entries. Just be sure to keep the dictionary entries in the list format you have and it should work out!

Comment: Just saw you want it all on one line: create a new variable `dictionary_output = ''` now just add entries as they are found  (instead of 'print' use `dictionary_output += (entry + ':' + str(len(d[entry])))` now you can `return dictionary_output` and it should give you one line

Answer (score 0):

you might want to reset the collect value at the beginning of each `for books in d[name]:` loop

Comment: how to reset the collcect value

Answer (score 0):

Using dictionary comprehensions, and some set operations:

```
def build_person_to_matches(d, name):
    return {n:len(set(d[n]) & set(d[name])) for n in d}
```

or, if you don't want name parameter to appear in match

```
def build_person_to_matches(d, name):
    return {n:len(set(d[n]) & set(d[name])) for n in d if n != name}
```

If you don't like using "&" for set intersection, you can be more descriptive

```
def build_person_to_matches(d, name):
    return {n:len(set(d[n]).intersection(d[name])) for n in d if n != name}
```